# How can I determine how deeply nested a child element is within a parent?

Tags: jquery

Given a child element, is there a simple means of determining how many parent tags separate it from a given selector?  Something like `.closest(selector)` which returns the number of `parent()` calls required to reach any element selected by the the given selector.

An (untested) implementation of what I'm looking for:

```
$.fn.distance = function(selector) {
  var $parent = $(selector); // TODO check that element exists
  var $current = $(this);
  var depth = 0;
  while ($current != $parent) {
    $current = $current.parent();
    ++depth;
  }
  return depth;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$element.parentsUntil( "selector" ).length
```

Answer (score 5):

See the [`.parentsUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/) method.

```
var seperatingTags = $(something).parentsUntil('div').size();
```